# Is "have a conversation between us X" idiomatic?

Tags: idioms

I am not sure why, but I find the expression "have a conversation between us X" where X is a number, a bit weird. Is the expression idiomatic?

Just so that we're fully clear on what I am asking, here's an example:

> Let's **have a conversation between us five** right now instead of waiting for John.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "have a conversation between us X"

is idiomatic, and

> Let's **have a conversation between us five** right now instead of waiting for John.

is perfectly fine.

Unfortunately, I cannot find a resource to provide, for more information.